# Test Babel transpiled(AMD) ES6 code in Karma + Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, ecmascript-6

I have written test in ES6, which is transpiled to ES5 in AMD format using Babel.
Now I want to run the test using Karma(+requirejs) and Jasmine, but getting following error:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (exports) {
    "use strict";

    describe("App", function () {
        it("tests something", function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
}
```

The test file looks like:

```
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
    "use strict";

    describe("App", function () {
        it("tests something", function () {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not transpiling to ES5 first, but use karma-babel-preprocessor.